# PIC:How to interface MPL115A1 pressure sensor to PIC24FJ16GA?

Tags: pic, sensor, spi

I have one pressure sensor which I want to interface to microcontroller PIC24FJ16GA to measure pressure.

I don't know which pin of controller to interface a sensor.

I am already using SPI1 in my project in that configuration controller is worked as a slave.

How to interface using SPI2?

I am little bit confusing when read a datasheet of controller.

If some demo code is available then is better understanding for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both SPI connections are handled the same way. Everywhere it has "x" in the datasheet, e.g. `SPIxCON1`, simply use a "2" to handle the second interface whenever you would use a "1" to handle the first.

Comment: But I am using SPI1 to slave mode and I want to use SPI2 to master mode.One more question is same controller pin is used for both communication????

Comment: @shailkorat: `RPIN20` through `RPIN23` control SPI input pins, and `RPORxx` control SPI output pins. Assuming you haven't decided to use too many for other features, you should have enough for both SPI ports. 5 input pins are available, and SPI slave needs 3 inputs, SPI master needs 1. This leaves 12 or 22 (depending on the package) pins for the 4 outputs.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question.I have one question is I have already written code like RPINR20bits.SCK1R=12 RPINR20bits.SDI1R=11
RPINR21bits.SS1R=13
RPOR5bits.RP10R=7 how this value come from I don't understand  properly.what is the meaning of this value??

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments. Post new questions please.